# Can't get the selected SelectList item to be selected in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

*I managed to solve the problem myself. See update 3 at the bottom.*

I'm making a `SelectList` of a `List<ApplicationUserViewModel>` like this:

```
List<ApplicationUserViewModel> selectableUsers = 
    auto.Map<List<ApplicationUserViewModel>>(users);

// Select the meeting owner:
foreach (ApplicationUserViewModel user in selectableUsers)
{
    if (user.Id == meeting.OwnerId)
    {
        user.Selected = true;
    }
}

// I don't know is this next step is needed:
string selectedValue = selectableUsers
    .Where(u => u.Selected)
    .Select(i => i.Id).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

SelectUserViewModel vm = new() { 
    SelectableUsers = new SelectList(selectableUsers, "Id", "FullName", selectedValue)
};
```

The viewmodel for my form-view looks like this:

```
public class SelectUserViewModel
{
    public Guid MeetingId { get; set; }
    public MeetingViewModel Meeting { get; set; }
    public SelectList SelectableUsers { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

`ApplicationUserViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationUserViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";

    // Lots of other properties ...

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

The dropdown in the view:

```
<select asp-for="UserId" asp-items="@Model.SelectableUsers">
</select>
```

The right user *does* have the property `Selected` set to `true`, yet when the rendered drop down is displayed on the page, the first item on the list is always selected.

**UPDATE** I did a bit of debugging, and found that in my view, all the items had the `Selected` property set to `False`. Why doesn't the `Selected`-property of my `ApplicationUserViewModel` get transferred to the `SelectList`?

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 2**

I have tried the suggestions given in the answer and the comments, but it hasn't gotten me any further. Now, my setup looks like this:

New viewmodel just for the purpose of making a selectlist:

```
public class SelectableApplicationUserViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Building a `List<ApplicationUserViewModel>`:

```
List<ApplicationUserViewModel> users = auto.Map<List<ApplicationUserViewModel>>
    (meeting.Summonings.Select(u => u.User)).ToList();
```

Setting the selected user:

```
foreach (ApplicationUserViewModel user in users)
{
    if (user.Id == meeting.OwnerId)
    {
        user.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

At this point, the correct user has his `Selected`-property set to `True`.

Translating the list into a `List<SelectableApplicationUserViewModel>`:

```
List<SelectableApplicationUserViewModel> selectableUsers = users
    .Select(s => new SelectableApplicationUserViewModel
{
    Id = s.Id.ToString(),
    Name = s.FullName,
    Selected = s.Selected
}).ToList();
```

At this point, the correct user *still* has his `Selected`-property set to `True`.

Getting the selected user to put in as the object later on:

```
SelectableApplicationUserViewModel selectedUser = selectableUsers
    .First(s => s.Selected);
```

The correct user is selected.

Building the viewmodel:

```
SelectUserViewModel vm = new()
{
    SelectableUsers = new SelectList(selectableUsers, "Id", "Name", selectedUser) // <-- Remember, this is the correct selected user.
    // other properties
};
```

And finally, arriving at the view:

```
<select asp-for="UserId" asp-items="@Model.SelectableUsers" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Select user ...</option>
</select>
```

and now all the users have their `Selected`-property set to `False`.

**Update 3**

Turns out, all I had to do was set the value for `UserId`, and then the selected user was correctly selected in the form!

Now the viewmodel is built like this:

```
SelectUserViewModel vm = new()
{
    MeetingId = meeting.Id,
    Meeting = auto.Map<MeetingViewModel>(meeting),
    SelectableUsers = new SelectList(users, "Id", "FullName"),
    UserId = meeting.OwnerId, // <-- This was the key!
};
```

And rendered in the view like this:

```
<select asp-for="UserId" asp-items="@Model.SelectableUsers" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Select a person from the list</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Pls show your view code too.

Comment: @Serge Added the view code.

Comment: Thanks,  I can't see UserId in your viewModel. Where it is from?

Comment: @Serge. Uhm, I might have forgotten to add some vital info. Please see the added viewmodel `SelectUserViewModel`.

Comment: Yes, and post the whole view too including model, form and post action

Comment: What does `selectedValue` contain during runtime?

Comment: @mxmissile I have updated my code a bit. Please see update 2. The correct user is selected, but is not maintained in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [this construct of `SelectList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_).
So it would seem the 4th parameter `selectedValue` would have to be an object, not the ID

```cs
var selectedValue = selectableUsers.Single(u => u.Selected);
```

or

```cs
var selectedValue = selectableUsers.Single(user.Id == meeting.OwnerId);
```

You don't actually need to put the `Selected` propery on your items. `SelectableUsers` will have a property `SelectedValue`.

edit: as you still run into problems: a `SelectList` contains `SelectListItem`s. It doesn't automap the properties of your custom type to the `SelectListItem`: for the constructor you use, you need to specify the Test and Value property name, but you can't specify the Selected property name. And the compiler cannot read your mind, so you need to tell it what to do. You could just build up the `SelectListItem`s yourself:

```cs
... = new SelectList(selectableUsers.Select(su =>
    new SelectListItem {
        Value = su.Id,
        Text = su.FullName,
        Selected = su.Selected,
    }));
```

(not sure if an explicit `.ToList()` is required. The constructor seems to take an IEnumerable)

edit 2:
quote: `SelectableUsers = new SelectList(selectableUsers, "Id", "Name", selectedUser)`

The specific constructor you are calling is generating a `List<SelectListItem>` for the input, using the property name you specify as second argument for the "Value" and that of the third for the "Text". Then, as fourth element, you set which object is selected by default.

This will generate the following equivalent code:

```cs
new SelectList(selectableUsers.Select(
    u => new SelectListItem {
        Value = su.Id,
        Text = su.Name,
        Selected = su == selectedUser,
    }));
```

*I.e. the `Selected` property of the `SelectListItem` will be set and **not** the Selected property of the  view model*. (There is **no** way to couple these together, as `bool` is a value type.) Actually, the view model `Selected` property is redundant for this use case.

If you want to know which item (object) is selected. You need to query `SelectableUsers.SelectedItem`.

Comment: That didn't make any difference. But the problem might be somewhere else. Please look at my updated question. I did some debugging.

Comment: I tried your updated suggestion, but still no success. I have updated my code a bit as well, among other things, I have made a viewmodel just for the purpose of building a `SelectList`. Please see update 2.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your effort. I solved it myself in the end. See update 3. My setup may not follow the convensions 100%. There is a reason for it that doesn't come out in my question, because I have simplified it a bit for clarity. Maybe over simplified and left out important info? Well, anyway - have a "useful" vote from me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SelectableUsers = new SelectList(selectableUsers, "Id", "Name", selectedUser.Id);
```